# Is it possible to use apple push notification service using jdk 1.4

Tags: java, ios, mobile, apple-push-notifications, jdk1.4

Is it possible to use *apple push notification* service using **jdk 1.4**? I can't use `japns` and `java apns` because atleast 1 of them is built using **1.5**.